# Coupons for In-app Billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

We are about to release an application on the Android Market, with In-app Billing for subscription that unlocks certain features for a the subscription period.

My boss now wants me to implement varying number of "**free** subscriptions" in the sense that:

1. The "lucky user" downloads & installs the application from the Android Market like any other customer (always free to install, but premium features require payment via In-app Billing).
2. The "lucky user" receives some key via email that allows him or her to avoid going through the In-app Billing checkout process (i.e. actually pay).
3. The key can only be used once.
4. Entering the key via a menu item, enables subscription for X months, **as if** he actually paid via In-app Billing.

The "key" basically acts like a coupon, but I haven't found any such option in the [Publisher's Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish).

Do you know of any such feature or a simple way to implement the above without duplicating the customer database on our (the publishers) server?

Comment: Isn't the main part of your question how you can prevent the user from using the code multiple times? Because the activation of the "Premium Features" shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I actually dove into this subject maybe 2, 3 months ago. My conclusion was that currently there's no way of setting up this system, without using your own server.

Generating unique coupon-codes and expiring them on use is pretty straightforward. Let the user enter the code, send a POST-request to your server, hash the code both client- and server-side and see if they match. Next, expire the code serverside and you're set. It does however make your app vulnerable to piracy (if it isn't already); if you have a high-profile app, make sure to implement security checks (e.g. check SSL certificates to prevent a man-in-the-middle attack).

The hard part is reinstating previously acquired 'freebies' when users reinstall your app or change phones/firmware. For this purpose you're going to need a stable and reliable (cross-device) form of identification (e.g. access to the user's main Google-account on the phone). If you use user-provided e-mailaddresses, it's too easy to just enter someone else's e-mailaddress. If you were to implement a coupon-system, I would advise against reinstating 'freebies'.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, which may save me lots of trial-and-error. Note that vulnerability to piracy is not an issue, because even the most secure methods (including SSL) are vulnerable to piracy, as shown in [this article](http://techcrunch.com/2011/11/14/siri-cracked-open-theoretically-opening-it-up-to-other-devices-or-even-android/). No point in trying to protect against the determined hacker. Just make it *more convenient* for the end user to pay... :)

Comment: Yes, I totally agree! The problem is: your boss may not ;)

Answer (score 2):

I  know this is a really old thread, but I had a similar need and found an official solution. For anyone who comes here for a solution:

Google introduced [`Promotional Codes`](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_onetime#Implement-promo) couple of years ago and that is exactly what you're looking for.
You can create Promo Codes on the Play Console under `Your App -> User Acquisition -> Promotion`.

> You can use promotions to give users a paid app or in-app product for free with a promo code. You can create promotions to reward loyal fans, acquire new users, and reconnect with previous users. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6321495).

Answer (score -3):

yuo can add a screen for enter a coupons.
and the user can go in there and insrert his code and if it is correct you can give him whatever you want.